# Will Windows 8.1 on an old hard drive work on a new machine?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1

I just received a refurbished version of my laptop from Dell. The model name is the same, but the only differences are that it has a higher resolution display, an i7, as opposed to the i5 in the original, and 2 more GB of RAM. I had kept my old hard drive before sending it for repair because I didn't want to give them my personal data. Now that I have a new laptop, can I install it and use it without any problems? The old hard drive has Windows 8.1 and the new machine is supposedly shipped with Windows 8.1 as well. I truly do not wish to go through the trouble of installing every program all over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just swap drives and use the repair function from the Win 8.1 DVD in case it doesn't boot.

You might have to reactivate Windows, but besides that drives and other things should be fixed by the system itself.

You might want to create a backup of the old disk first, just in case.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I forgt to mention that the Windows 8.1 license is OEM, so I will not be able to use the hard drive in the new laptop. Notwithstanding, thank you for the informative answer.

Comment: @Skipher Just to note: depending on where you live, the OEM ructions might not apply and you might be able to reactivate it just fine. If in doubt, ask Dell.